# Reputation tab bug misreports numbers first time

Tags: bug, reputation

I've seen this a few times recently.

The first time I load the reputation tab, if there is reputation change today and yesterday on the same question, it (sometimes?) counts the today number wrong.

[image]

In fact, $290$ is exactly twice the total reputation value of the given answer, including yesterday's. The $143$ on the left is correct ($145$ for the answer, minus $2$ for a downvote on another answer.)

If I reload the page, I get the correct values.

[image]

Comment: This probably belongs in some global SE Meta, since I can't believe the code would be customized to Math.SE.

Comment: I started noticing such discrepancies (before versus after reloading the page) approximately 2 years ago, and just assumed that it was a longstanding bug.

Comment: I notice this regularly, but *only* on Math SE.